# setting options in select tag in table using closest

Tags: jquery, ajax

I m trying to set dynamic options in select tag which is in table that can have any number of row based on condition.

So got the data from ajax and trying to set it but unable to do so

```
$('#cb_table').on('change', 'select[name="batch_month"]', function() {
    var selectedMonth=$(this).val();
    var course_id=$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="course_name[]"]').attr('course-id');
    alert(selectedMonth+'abc '+course_id);
    $.ajax({
                 type : "POST",
                 url : "<?php echo base_url().'Bookings/fetch_course_batches/';?>",
                 data : {'course' : course_id,'start_date_m' : selectedMonth},
                 dataType : 'json',
                 success : function(data) {
                   var formatted_data='';
                   $.each(data.message, function (i,val) {
                     formatted_data+='<option value="'+val['batch_id']+'">'+val['start_date']+' '+val['end_date']+' '+val['batch_time']+'</option>';
                   });
                    var data1=$(this).closest('tr').find('select[name="batch_date_time[]"]').val(formatted_data);


                }
             });

  });
```

Comment: What you mean by _but unable to do so_?!

Comment: i mean not able to set those options in select... no options are being added

Comment: Add your relevant HTML code please. and show us the output of `console.log(data)`.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: html is being rendered using jquery $.each(data.message, function (i,val) {
                            tr+='<tr>';
                            tr+='<td><select class="form-control" id="batch_date_time[]" name="batch_date_time[]"><option value="">--Select Date/Time--</option></select></td>';
                            tr+='</tr>';

                          });
                          $('#course_batch_details').append(tr);

Comment: there is no error but var data1=$(this).closest('tr').find('select[name="batch_date_time[]"]').val(formatted_data);
isnot working for select tag

Comment: Show us the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: {"status":"success","message":[{"id":"1","course_name":"ABC","batch_time":"00:00:00","fee":"1000","start_date":"2018-01-11","end_date":"0000-00-00"}]}

Comment: in formatted data it is forming options properly

Comment: can any one help me in that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using **.val()** for appending option which is wrong . you should append html like

```
$('select').append('<option val="1">First</option>');
```

so in your case it would be

```
 var data1=$(this).closest('tr').find('select[name="batch_date_time[]"]').append(formatted_data);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I tried that it's not working

Comment: I got it somewhere you should try one of these $('select').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One'}));
$('select').append('<option val="1">One</option>');
var option = new Option(text, value);
$('select').append($(option));

Comment: i did a trial   and added this before ajax its working $(this).closest('tr').find('select[name="batch_date_time[]"]').append($('<option>',{value:1,text:'One'}));